# What does "wage concession" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I googled and found that "wage concession" means an agreement to raise wages.

However, I'm perplexed when I read the following, which defines it as a pay cut.

> When your company hits difficult financial times, you may be forced to
> make some hard decisions. A way to offset costs is to ask your staff
> to take **wage concessions**. Your staff can often tell when changes are
> coming. Learning what to say when you ask an employee to take a pay
> cut can be helpful when addressing this difficult task. **Wage concessions** provide an alternative to layoffs.
> (from https://smallbusiness.chron.com/say-ask-employee-wage-concessions-11610.html)

I want to ask if this article used it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: "I googled and found that "wage concession" means an agreement to raise wages".

I'm afraid that Google is not always a good friend. It has given you only part of the answer. *Wage concession* means a circumstance or agreement where somebody agrees to make a concession in respect of wages.

Since there are typically two parties to a wage negotiation, and they typically have contrary objectives, a concession could be made either way.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong. A wage concession by an employer could be an agreement to pay higher wages. A wage concession by an employee could be an agreement to work for lower wages.